# How exactly does $A(\alpha x + \lambda y) = \alpha A(x) + \lambda A(y)$ show that $A(0)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was debating with a friend about how (for linear map $A:V\mapsto W$), showing that for arbitrary vectors $x,y \in V$ and arbitrary scalars $\lambda, \alpha$, $A(\alpha x + \lambda y) = \alpha A(x) + \lambda A(y)$ holds the implies that $A(0)=0$.

I said that it holds since you can 'take' $\alpha, \lambda = 0$ and then indeed $A(0)=0$.

He said however, that it holds by taking the arbitrary vectors $x,y = 0$, and so then you do have that giving the $0$-vector as input always returns the $0$-vector, but that with my way of doing it I wasn't technically giving the $0$-vector as input so it wasn't exactly showing that $A(0\text{-vector})=0\text{-vector}$.

I understand his way of doing it but want to know if my reasoning is right or what he said is correct, meaning that you can't just take the scalars to be $0$ and then any vector.

Comment: Your approach is correct.

Comment: Taking the scalar to be zero is correct (and in this case, the vectors $x,y$ can be anything). The other approach is also correct because we would have $A(0)=A(0)+A(0)$ which implies $A(0)=0$ by subtracting from both sides.

Comment: The other approach would have $(\alpha+\lambda)A(0)$ on the right-hand side, which is sufficient (since we have the freedom to choose $\alpha\ne1-\lambda$.